# JAVA How do you put a global variable into a function parameter?

Tags: java, string, function, methods, global-variables

I'm attempting to practice classes methods since I'm very new to JAVA. In my full program I am using other global variables and they are working fine within my other methods. My question is how do i get the public String y to work inside the parameters of my isNum() method so that inside any method I can use isNum(y);  The way it is now the String y is only within the scope of isNum but I want y to be global inside the paramters of isNum and within it. Simple answers as possible thank you so much.

```
public static String y;
public static boolean isNum(String y){

for(int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++){

if(!(y.charAt(i) >= 48 && y.charAt(i) <= 57)){

    return false;
    }
}

return true;

}
```

I want to use isNum in this loop and transfer the value of x into y.
I know x is an int and y is a string. How would I make that work?

```
        x = input.nextInt();

        if(isNum(y){
        while(x <=0 || x > 3){
             System.out.println("Choose a correct gear number: ");

             x = input.nextInt();
        }
        switch(x){
            case 1:
            System.out.println("You're in Gear 1");
                break;
            case 2:
            System.out.println("Gear 2");
                break;

            case 3:
            System.out.println("Gear3");
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: java doesn't have functions, nor global variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `isNum` to access the static `y` variable, qualify it with the class name - `ClassName.y`.

When you write the unqualified variable name `y` inside your method, the local variable `y` hides the `static` variable of the same name.

EDIT : After re-reading your question, I'm not sure if your `isNum` method even needs to have the `y` parameter. If you want that method to use the static variable `y`, you can simply change its signature to `public static boolean isNum()` and leave the method body unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

global variables don't have to put into function.just use them directly!

In one class,use them directly.

In another class,use *ClassName.var*.

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear what you are trying to do....
if the function will always check if the "global" variable y is a number you should simply create a class like this:

```
public class global
{
    private static String y;

    public static boolean isNum(){...}//no need to get y as parameter
}
```

The thing you should pay attention to is that Java is Object Oriented so
you can't just have a global variable on it's own... it should be a static variable in a class that has static methods to deal with that variable